# Does generally RISC processors have lower power consumption than CISC processors?

Tags: architecture, processor, microprocessors

I usually read that RISC processors usually have a lower power consumption than CISC processors for example:  ARM implementations (1-2 W) to x86 implementations (5 - 36 W).
Does that apply for all the different RISC and CISC processors, or there are some excepltions.

Why this big difference?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about CPU power consumption in general. Stack Overflow is for practical programming questions.

Comment: @Mat - All software runs on hardware. No software runs without hardware. The firmware compilers are all software. I find your lack of vision disturbing, padawan.... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

No, they don't.

It was commonly believed in the past that RISC CPUs were more power friendly, mostly due to the large overhead of maintaining the large ROMs needed for CISC. However, [a recent study](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/vertical/papers/2013/hpca13-isa-power-struggles.pdf) comparing several workloads on multiple platforms finally ended that myth, stating:

> there is nothing fundamentally more energy efficient in one ISA class
>   or the other.

It's still true that many **implementations** of these ISAs are directed at certain market segments that still reflect this classification, you'll find more x86 at the segments with higher power envelopes such as PCs and servers, and more ARM at the low power and embedded segments, but these are mostly design points and marketing decisions. There's nothing fundamental preventing a CISC ISA from entering lower power domains.

Don't mix that with backward compatibility - x86 for e.g. would have a hard time reducing power while still keeping all legacy modes and specialized ISA, but it's another issue. It's also not a real block, as can be seen in Atom based implementations, some of which even going below 1W TDP

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, there are no exceptions. ARM is for low power applications like mobile phones, tablets, PDAs while CISC is for desktop, server computing.

The big difference is not because of the instruction set architecture but because of the micro-architecture or the underlying machine implementation which is pipelined and sophisticated in case of CISC and simple in case of RISC. RISC assumes that computer has finite number of transistors and what are the most number of instructions that can fit onto the computer. That is not the case for CISC.

Look at Coursera course on computer architecture particularly Lecture 1 part 5(L1s5)